# Access to service in Docker container connected to VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, docker

I set up a Linux server (VirtualBox VM for now)

In that server I run a `Docker container` containing two things:

- An app with web interface on certain port
- Open VPN Client

I can access that app (from my host machine, since Linux is VM guest) and everything works fine until I connect VPN.

VPN works - traffic goes through it but I can't connect to my app anymore (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT).

So my goal is to:

- Have a server in Docker container where all the traffic goes through VPN
- Be able to access that server/container in my local network (as I do now when VPN is not connected)

How can I achieve it?

This is how my .ovpn file looks like

```
client
auth-user-pass
ping 5
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ns-cert-type server
verb 3
route-metric 1
proto udp
ping-exit 30
cipher AES-256-CBC

// cetrificate here

remote <remote-host-ip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a routing inside the docker?

Try adding these via command line:

```
ip rule add from X.X.X.X table 128
ip route add table 128 to y.y.y.0/24 dev eth0
ip route add table 128 default via Z.Z.Z.Z
```

Where:
X.X.X.X is the LAN address of the docker

Y.Y.Y.0 is the network address for the LAN of docker e.g 192.168.1.0/24

ETH0 is your LAN interface

Z.Z.Z.Z is the Lan gateway i.e Your router IP most likely

Note that these commands don't survive a reboot. So if you would like to keep them, put them in /etc/rc.local with a "sleep 30" command.